# Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined for aws-sdk js v3 for dynamodb client

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nestjs, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to connect a nestjs backend (node) with a dynamodb table using @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb but I have a server error:

```
[Nest] 24019  - 24/08/2021, 21:19:38   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined
```

from
`node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-buffer-from/src/index.ts:4:8`

I instantiate my client like so:

```
import { DynamoDB } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";


// Full DynamoDB Client
const client = new DynamoDB({
    region: 'eu-west-2',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    }
});
```

I use dotenv to build process env variable

I searched the web, but except for some post saying that I need to lowercase credentials object key which is already done on my code I found nothing

Answer (score 0):

In order to use .env in NestJS you will need @nestjs/config
install it by running npm i @nestjs/config
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot()
     ],
     controllers: [AppController],
     providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Example of nodejs sdk v3.

```
const dynamoClient = new DynamoDBClient(
    {
        region: process.env.DB_REGION,
        endpoint: process.env.DB_ENDPOINT,
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: process.env.DB_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.DB_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        }
    }
);
const dbDocumentClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(
    dynamoClient
);
```